# lib class not found

Tags: magento-1, error, fatal-error, class, autoloader

I am loading a custom class from the lib folder and I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'NameSpace_MyClass' not found in /dir/to/site/app/code/local/NameSpace/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/ModuleController.php on line 93

My class directory tree looks like this

```
./lib
    /NameSpace
        /MyClass.php
    /Varian
    /Zend
```

The declaration in the controller looks like:

```
$class = new NameSpace_MyClass($id);
```

And `MyClass.php` looks like this

```
class MyClass{

    private $id;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

How am I able to call this class? I'm under the impression I don't need to do anything in an xml file to load this as Magento/Zend auto includes files in the `lib` folder. Is this correct?

Comment: Add      require_once Mage::getBaseDir('base').DS.'lib'.DS.'Namespace'.DS.'MyClass.php';   in your controller file

Comment: Hi, @saravanavelu I have added that into the `_constructor` of MyController behind a `if(!class_exists('NameSpace_MyClass'))` and it throws up this error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class MyClass` in the class file where it declares the class name

Comment: @saravanavelu likewise if I call the same code in just the controller action

Comment: @saravanavelu please submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. My problem is now different and i'll create a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Magento autoloader to find it, the class must be called `NameSpace_MyClass`, not `MyClass`  and also not `NameSpace\MyClass`

If you want to use libraries with real namespaces, you need an additional autoloader that is PSR-0 or PSR-4 compatible. I can recommend the [Magento-PSR-0-Autoloader](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Magento-PSR-0-Autoloader)

With this extension, you would register the namespace in `config.xml` like this:

```
<psr0_namespaces>
    <NameSpace />
</psr0_namespaces>
```

Then, define a real namespace:

```
namespace NameSpace;

class MyClass{

    private $id;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

And use to the class like this:

```
use NameSpace\MyClass;
$class = new MyClass($id);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Changed the class name and it was perfect.

Comment: Hi,Fabian, I am using this monolog module https://github.com/aleron75/magemonolog, on local it is working fine, but on server it throws "Fatal error: Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found in" is this somehow related to

Comment: on local, php version is 5.6, on server it is 5.5.38

Comment: @Haris no, it must be something else that's different between the two installations

Answer (score 0):

You have *nix system and the file system is case senstive. This means your directories has to be the same name, EXACT same name, as the file:

```
     NameSpace_MyClass
/lib/Namespace/MyClass.php
```

What can you see? If you haven't seen it yet you need to increase this ability, it will help you a lot with Magento ;-) ... `S != s`

Comment: Hi, The casing error was a transposing error, the directory is called `NameSpace` on live.